# White background while switching to webview

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview

I have a button, onclick of that button a webview load a html from asset, it takes a while to load that html page, so in between a while color appears, in short words while switching to webview white color comes in background, i researched a lot but  not got any thing.

How to fix ??? Kindly help.

Answer (score 4):

Try to set the background color to the `WebView`:

```
webview.setBackgroundColor(0x01000000);
```

**EDIT:** if you want a black color:

```
webview.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
```

If this doesn't work for you, I suggest you this workaround:

1. Add the `WebView` inside a **container** (like a `FrameLayout`) and the set the background of
   the container to black
2. Turn the `WebView` **INVISIBLE** when you need to load a new page
3. Attach a custom `WebViewClient` to the your WebView using [setWebViewClient()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)). Your custom WebViewClient will set the WebView visible again when the page is loaded. During the load process, you will see a black background.

> ```
>   webView.setWebViewClient(new InternalWebViewClient());
>   //...
>   private class InternalWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
>
>      @Override
>      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
>         super.onPageFinished( view, url );
>         webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>      }
>   }
> ```

Comment: Thanks,it is not working, if i want black color then is it possible?

Comment: Still not working, There might be some confusion what happening is when i click a button a white color comes and after that html page loaded. I want to get rid out off that white color and replace it with black, is there is a way @bonnyz